# How to add new columns to a dataframe filled with a value of another cell based on conditions per cluster/group?

Tags: r, conditional-statements, grouping

I have a dataframe `xmpl` with the grouping or cluster variable `ID`. I want to add a new column `a1_momo` which is filled with one specific value from column `a1` for each row per `ID` based on the following conditions:

`'BM' == 1 & 'W2' == 0 & 'dt' == 1`

that lead to one clear identified single match per cluster, except for no such row is existing.

```
xmpl <- data.frame(ID = c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3),
                  BM = c(0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1),
                  W2 = c(0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0),
                  dt = c(1,2,1,2,1,1,2,2,1,1),
                  a1 = c(3,2,1,2,2,3,2,2,3,NA))
```

```
> xmpl
   ID BM W2 dt a1
1   1  0  0  1  3
2   1  0  0  2  2
3   1  1  0  1  1
4   1  1  0  2  2
5   1  1  1  1  2
6   2  0  0  1  3
7   2  0  0  2  2
8   2  1  0  2  2
9   2  1  1  1  3
10  3  1  0  1 NA
```

Solely `xmpl[3,]` fits the conditions for `'ID' == 1` so I want to fill the value of `xmpl$a1[3]` to each row of the cluster into the new column `a1_momo`.
For `'ID' == 2` there is no match to conditions so therefore `a1_momo` should be filled with `NA` for the rows clustered in `'ID' == 2`.
Lastly, `'ID' == 3` contains a row matching all conditions but has no value for `a1`.

---

The result I wish to get:

```
> xmpl
   ID BM W2 dt a1 a1.momo
1   1  0  0  1  3       1
2   1  0  0  2  2       1
3   1  1  0  1  1       1
4   1  1  0  2  2       1
5   1  1  1  1  2       1
6   2  0  0  1  3      NA
7   2  0  0  2  2      NA
8   2  1  0  2  2      NA
9   2  1  1  1  3      NA
10  3  1  0  1 NA      NA
```

---

My limited knowledge in prorgramming with R led me to the following conclusion:

I could produce a new dataframe that is grouped for my cluster variable so I have only one row per `ID`. The only function I know to do nearly the thing I want, is `aggregate` but it needs a summary function for specification. Instead of that I need someting to define my conditions by which the new dataframe can be filled with the one specific value (or NA) per cluster, e.g. a `ifelse`-specification.

So there would be something like:

`xmpl.2<-not.aggregate(xmpl[,'a1'],list(xmpl$ID),ifelse(...))`

```
> xmpl.2
  Group.1 a1
1       1  1
2       2 NA
3       3 NA
```

Afterwards I imagined something like `merge`-ing it together `by` the grouping variable `ID` with the suffix `.momo`. (because of course the real data contains more than one "`a1`")

`xmpl<-merge(xmpl,xmpl.2,by=1,suffixes=c("",".momo"))`

My questions therefore are:

- Is that one way to go? Which `[package::function]` do I need to use then instead of `aggregate`?
- How do I fill in a new column with a specific value *based on another cell* when using `ifelse`-functions?

---

Days of research ended up with nothing so I'm typing this example.
I guess there's a more elegant solution I can't see. Very grateful for help.

Comment: What is the value of `a1.momo` if multiple rows for an `ID` meet the conditions, but have different values for `a1`?

Comment: thx for asking this really important question: in the real data it's simply not the case: one or none ;) - meeting the condition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I bet there's a concise one-liner with base R, but here's a simple dplyr approach. I join the data to a version that extracts matching rows, one per ID/a1.mono. I'm not sure how you want to deal with potential situations where there are multiple matching rows within an ID, with different a1 values.

```
library(dplyr)
xmpl |> 
  left_join(
    xmpl |>
      filter(BM == 1 & W2 == 0 & dt == 1 & !is.na(a1)) |>
      mutate(a1.mono = a1) |>
      distinct(ID, a1.mono)
  )
```